# how to check custom property of added Item

Tags: 2007, list, feature, event-handlers

There is a boolean column I added to a custom list, but I also have a feature on this custom list so that when a Item is added i have to check if this column exists or not and then its value.

now i am using this code,

```
 class GetCustomerDetails : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            if ((bool)properties.ListItem.Properties["Invoice Generated"] == true)
            {
            }
         }
    }
```

how can i check if this property exists before checking its value and if am checking property value right way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the properties.ListItem.Fields to get the SPFieldCollection and check for the existence of your field in the collection.